# Adding non-related widgets to dashboards

Tags: dashboard, widget

Im currently designing an internal application which will get used by a large amount of employees in our company. The application will be used for stuff like managing customer data, changing contracts, uploading documents etc.

One part of the application will be the dashboard, which will be the only area that displays kind of "personal" or user-related data.

Of course there will be graphs and diagrams that display performance and stuff like this but now im wondering if it is recommended to display data that is not application related just as a little "extra" and to make the user feel a bit better.

Example:

Hello Thomas, its Friday the 21th and the current temperature is 20°.

The part of the date could be useful since the users often communicate with customers via phone and exchange data, so i could avoid making them leave the application and checking the date on their operating system but stuff like the weather information would not be application related at all.

Or maybe add a widget that shows some quotes or facts once a day so users actually get excited to open the application for the first time each day (since they will open it every day).

Would you say stuff like this adds unnecessary weight or can add a nice little touch to the UX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Do some thorough research across your user base (your own employees) and find out what features they would request if they had a personal dashboard which helped them be more effective at their jobs.

It's noble to try to design considerate software, and add a useful or friendly touch, but I would put the question the other way: Are users missing having the date and weather displayed on your internal app? Have they communicated this to the product or design team?

**Space to display important data is at a premium on a dashboard (and almost all) views. Add information irrelevant to their jobs (noise) at your peril.**

Dashboards almost always involve tradeoffs of compressing important metrics, time sensitive data and status of items pertinent to a workflow. Whole books, articles and websites tackle the problems of signal to noise ratios, space limitations, scrolling and displaying urgency.

Find people's pain points; use those to figure out how to display meaningful yet universal information that helps people with where your current software is falling short.